How to edit nodal coordinates of abaqus input file to create identical mesh
I am trying to create an identical mesh on the opposite faces of my geometry (a cuboid with some partitional surface features), so I made three node sets on three faces. I have meshed the model. In the input file, I could see the nodal numbers of the created sets. I thought I would modify the z-coordinate of set-1, y-coordinate of set-2, and x-coordinate of set- to make the nodes for opposite faces.
I have Matlab and Abaqus.
Could anyone please suggest how to solve this or what I should do?
Thanks

Seems tricky approach but yes, you can try this. But the best way to do it is using Python script. You can do this approach in Abaqus CAE and create a python script from commands in abaqus.rpy file. For more help, write me an email.
